# Expected end of line error in middle of codeline

Tags: vbscript

I have this simple vbscript, but windows gives me an error when I'm trying to run it. I've never worked with vbscript before and i tried to google, but could figure out why. I'm getting expected end of line error at line 1, character 16. Does anyone see anything? 
Also, I'm coding this in notepad and running it by double clicking the file. Is there any other way i should do it?

```
Dim WithEvents Button As CommandButton
Private Sub Application_StartUp(Cancel As Boolean)
Set Button = CommandButtons.Add("Click me")
End SubPrivate Sub Button_Click()
Msgbox "Clicked", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not valid *VBScript* (`As XXX` is not valid) is it VBA/6/.Net ?

Comment: It might be VBA. Does VBA files have the .vbs extension as well?

Comment: This is Outlook VBA, most likely. It would not have a `vbs` extension. It would have a class (`cls`) or module (`bas`) extension.

Comment: Um, "it might be VBA"? It's your script, that you're writing. (You wrote "I'm coding this in notepad", didn't you?) If you can't tell what it is, how are we to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Since it was mentioned that notepad is being used for this and looking at the code this certainly appears to be code to add a button to a Form Based application using VBScript in Visual Studio.

VBScript via notepad is not really good at being used for creating GUI dialog boxes and such.  A sample code of what would work using Notepad is as such:

```
toRepeat = InputBox("What should I repeat?", "Echo", "Hello World")
MsgBox toRepeat
```

Whatever is typed in to the input box will be repeated in this example.

If Visual Studio is not available and there is an interest in building a form based application then it may be possible to create User Forms in VBA via Word or Excel.  The following site gives a good tutorial for creating a User Form application in Excel: [Excel VBA Userform - Easy Excel Macros](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html)

In case there is interest, I recently wrote in to my blog an explanation of the different flavors of VB that are available: [VBA vs VBSCRIPT vs Visual Basic](https://seanwoodward-public.sharepoint.com/Blog/Post/4/VBA-vs-VBSCRIPT-vs-Visual-Basic)

Thanks,

Sean W.